# Writing Element({...props}) instead of Element(props)

Tags: reactjs

I saw somewhere this notation `function Element({...props})`, but you could also simply write `function Element(props)`. Why should you write this with spread notation?

```
function Element({...props}) {
  // render element here
}
```

versus

```
function Element(props) {
  // render element here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might take a few props later and leave the rest:

```js
function Component({ foo, bar, ...props }) {
```

Doing this ahead of time might save you some typing later.
This is the only thing I can think of why you would do this.

Answer (score 0):

It is called a spread operator

You can use the ES6 Spread operator to pass props to a React component. Let's take an example for a component that expects two props:

```
function App() {
  return <Hello firstName="Ahmed" lastName="Bouchefra" />;
}
```

Using the Spread operator, you would write the following code instead:

```
function App() {
  const props = {firstName: 'Ahmed', lastName: 'Bouchefra'};
  return <Hello {...props} />;
}
```

This explanation is from [here](https://www.techiediaries.com/react-spread-operator-props-setstate/)